# Why does my webpage look different upon resizing the browser window VS on mobile?

Tags: css

This is what my webpage looks like when resizing the browser window

[image: 1]

This is what my webpage looks like on mobile

[image: 2]

As you can see, everything looks messed up on mobile, but it actually looks alright when resizing my browser window. How come? Is there an easy fix to this? Here's my code. I'm kinda lost when it comes to CSS, and I'm just looking for a quick-fix to this.

```css
    body {
    background-image: url("https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/sa_pixar_virtualbg_coco_16x9_9ccd7110.jpeg");
}

.header {

}

#heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

select, input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Spinnaker', sans-serif;
}

#deviceSelector select {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
    <h1 id="heading">Tidsbokning</h1>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <form action='' method='post' id='firstForm' autocomplete='off'>
        <label for='people'>Välj antal personer</label>
        <select id='people' name='people'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
        </select>
        <div id='deviceSelector'>
            <label for='device1'>Välj enhet (person 1)</label><br>
            <select id='device1' name='device1'>
                <option value='VR'>Virtual Reality</option>
                <option value='RacingSim'>Racing Simulator</option>
                <option value='PC'>Dator</option>
                <option value='Switch'>Nintendo Switch</option>
            </select><br>
        </div>
        <label for='time'>Välj tid</label>
        <select id='time' name='time'>
            <option value='30'>30 min</option>
            <option value='60'>1h</option>
            <option value='90'>1h 30min</option>
            <option value='120'>2h</option>
            <option value='150'>2h 30 min</option>
            <option value='180'>3h</option>
            <option value='210'>3h 30 min</option>
            <option value='240'>4h</option>
            <option value='270'>4h 30 min</option>
            <option value='300'>5h</option>
        </select>
        <label for='priceTotal'>Pris</label>
        <input type='text' id='priceTotal' name='priceTotal' value='50 kr' disabled>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Fortsätt'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider using cross-platform frameworks like [Ocsigen](https://ocsigen.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `.container` width in mobile using media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {width: 300px;}
}
```

### full code

```css
body {
    background-image:url("https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/sa_pixar_virtualbg_coco_16x9_9ccd7110.jpeg");
}

.header {

}

#heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .container {width: 300px;}
 }

select, input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Spinnaker', sans-serif;
}

#deviceSelector select {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
    <h1 id="heading">Tidsbokning</h1>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <form action='' method='post' id='firstForm' autocomplete='off'>
        <label for='people'>Välj antal personer</label>
        <select id='people' name='people'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
        </select>
        <div id='deviceSelector'>
            <label for='device1'>Välj enhet (person 1)</label><br>
            <select id='device1' name='device1'>
                <option value='VR'>Virtual Reality</option>
                <option value='RacingSim'>Racing Simulator</option>
                <option value='PC'>Dator</option>
                <option value='Switch'>Nintendo Switch</option>
            </select><br>
        </div>
        <label for='time'>Välj tid</label>
        <select id='time' name='time'>
            <option value='30'>30 min</option>
            <option value='60'>1h</option>
            <option value='90'>1h 30min</option>
            <option value='120'>2h</option>
            <option value='150'>2h 30 min</option>
            <option value='180'>3h</option>
            <option value='210'>3h 30 min</option>
            <option value='240'>4h</option>
            <option value='270'>4h 30 min</option>
            <option value='300'>5h</option>
        </select>
        <label for='priceTotal'>Pris</label>
        <input type='text' id='priceTotal' name='priceTotal' value='50 kr' disabled>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Fortsätt'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries, add this in to your CSS

```
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
```